# How do I turn off the "Turn on Facebook Notifications" popup?

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention, facebook-notifications

Facebook recently started spamming with "See your notifications in the corner of your computer screen, even when Facebook is closed."

Option "Not Now" means that the nagging returns soon.

Selecting "Turn On" is not wanted as I am not interested in getting spam from Facebook.

Dialog itself may be easily blocked with AdBlock, unfortunately modal part (invisible part of dialog that blocking using FB while message appears) has dynamic class names that defeat AdBlock filtering.

[image]

How can I get rid of that?

Note that I prefer to keep my Facebook account with current notifications, I am not looking for nuclear solutions like "disable all notifications".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instructions for how to stop the "Turn on Facebook Notifications" pop-up**

1. Click the green "**Turn on**" button in the popup window.
2. If you havent already turned off "off site" notifications in the browser, a browser dialog should then pop up asking whether you want to allow notifications from facebook.com. Select the "**Always block on this site**" or "**Never Allow**" options (or equivalent). If you have already turned off browser notifications via the padlock icon at the left of the address bar, then you are already sorted and this step will not be necessary.

After doing those steps you will no longer see the "Turn on Facebook Notifications" pop-up appearing

Source: https://www.facebook.com/fluffbustingpurity/photos/a.10150533570152559.422225.408502197558/10155394849117559/?type=3

Comment: Not ideal, as now browsers will keep asking me (on every browser, on very computer, after every settings reset). But given that it is FB there is probably no better solution.

Answer (score -1):

You need to go to your Facebook profile settings and then go to notifications settings.
There are 4 different options, in desktop and mobiles you can turn off all the notifications.

Comment: What are those options and how that will help to OP?

Comment: I am not interested in killing all notifications, I want to keep current settings and see notifications when I visit facebook website.